# How to eliminate duplicate products in odoo purchase order product line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

While creating purchase order, If I add the same products twice , it creates two different product lines instead of updating the quantities of the same product.

Please anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a model which inherits from `purchase.order.line` and override its create function this way:

```
class purchase_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherits = 'purchase.order.line'

    @api.one
    def create(self, vals):
        same_line = self.search([('product_id', '=', vals.get('product_id', False)),
                                 ('order_id', '=', vals.get('order_id', False))])
        if same_line:
            total_qty = same_line.product_qty + vals.get('product_qty', 0)
            vals.update({
                'product_qty': total_qty,
            })
            same_line.write(vals)
            return same_line
        else:
            return super(purchase_order_line, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: what does this code do ?  in which model in odoo ? while creating purchase order, it doesnt show any results

Comment: You must create a new model which inherits from `purchase.order.line`. I'm going to edit the answer to show you how to.

Comment: That should only work once you have pressed the *Save* button of the `purchase.order` form. You won't be able to see the addition just after adding a new line without saving.

Comment: Yes, i created a separate .py file and then had put your code and exactly did the same as u said in the previous comment.

Comment: I'm thinking that the best place to apply these lines is in the `create` function of `purchase.order` and checking the `One2many field` which relates it to `purchase.order.line` (instead of overriding directly `purchase.order.line` create method)

Answer (score 0):

just inherit purchase.order.line model from purchase module and overide create method.

```
class purchase_order_line(models.Model):
_inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    same_line = self.search([('product_id', '=', vals.get('product_id', False)),
                             ('order_id', '=', vals.get('order_id', False))])
    if same_line:
        total_qty = same_line.product_qty + vals.get('product_qty', 0)
        vals.update({
            'product_qty': total_qty,
        })
        same_line.write(vals)
        return same_line
    else:
        return super(purchase_order_line, self).create(vals)
```